# Shall i use newly generated jks file with old password ,alias and keystore password for generating signed apk file?

Tags: android-studio

Previously,I was using android studio 2.3 and I have generated so many signed and generated so many APK files in android studio.After updating to 3.0,I am facing problem while generating APK files.I am getting the following error  **failed to read key from store key store was tampered with, or password was incorrect**.So i have generated new **jks** file with old credentials.Shall i use this jks file for  signed generating signed APK file?

Comment: Unless you publish to the Play Store, that shouldn't be a problem. On the other hand, the Play Store requires each APK to be signed with the same key for updates

Comment: key means password right ? I am going to publish to play store only. @chade_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate an APK it needs to be sealed with a keystore that has unique footprint every time u generate it.

If you are building for dev. and testing that wouldn't be a problem, to always get a different footprint (use different cert)
but when u publish u need it to always be build with the same cert or you wouldn't be able to update it in the future.

when you build (with the new android studio 3.0) you have the option to press generate signed apk

so best advice would be if it's for production keep that keystore in a safe place + backup.

*if its just for dev, just ignore this message your getting.

here is more reading on the subject >

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html